# Append string in file name using powershell

Tags: powershell, file-rename

I am trying to append string in the file name.

```
$cstzone = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")
$csttime = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeFromUtc((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime(), $cstzone)
$d = Get-Date $csttime -f "dd-MM-yyyy"
$t = Get-Date $csttime -f "HH:mm"
Write-Host "Date : " $d
Write-Host "Time : " $t

gci C:\Result.jtl | % { rename-item –Path $_.FullName –Newname ( $_.basename + $t + $_.extension) }
```

**Expected**

Result_14:42.jtl

**Error**

```
rename-item : Cannot rename the specified target, because it represents a path or device name.
At line:10 char:25
+ ... t.jtl | % { rename-item –Path $_.FullName –Newname ( $_.basename + $t ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Rename-Item], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have colons in file names, they are reserved for drive letters. You can use a tostring to get date in different format:

```
(Get-Date).ToString("hh-mm")
```

Comment: Thanks. I used the $t = $t -replace ':','-' to replace colon.